# Create vector from distance and vector

Tags: c#, vector, xna, distance

How can I create vector from another vector and a distance?

For example, with a `vector3d(1,1,2)` and distance 12, create another vector that has the same direction but is longer by 12 units.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to find the [unit vector](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_vector) in the direction you want; in XNA this is given by `Vector3.Normalize`. Then you can [scalar multiply](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scalar_multiplication) that unit vector (which has, by definition, length = 1) by the final distance.

Ex.:

```
var originalVector = new Vector3(1, 1, 2);
var finalLength = originalVector.Length + 12; // "longer by 12", this could be whatever you want
originalVector.Normalize(); // make it a unit vector
var finalVector = originalVector * finalLength;
```

Comment: But I don't have two vectors. I just have one vector and one distance

Comment: Then you can simply assign the result of `originalVector * finalLength`to `originalVector`. I'm illustrating with separate variables but you can do whatever you want, the maths are the same.

Comment: well, screw me ... here was I was with my "complex" pytagore maths in my game to calculate all movements... I guess this is what happens when you starts with no class in a domain ...

Answer (score 0):

Asik's answer is 100% correct from the mathematical standpoint. If you want the enlarged vector to be in the original one use

```
var originalVector = originalVector * finalLength;
```