# Generation random vector within a distance from template

Tags: r, random, generator, distance

I have found similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24268216/create-vector-from-distance-and-vector):but it does not refer to R. 
I would like to generate randomly a numeric vector which lies a defined distance from a defined numeric vector.

A=c(12,34,-2)
Distance=z

Find b=c(rnorm(1),rnorm(1),rnorm(1)) with dist(A, b) < z

Any tip for me? 
Best

Answer (score 1):

Randomly pick a point on the unit sphere and add it to your existing point. [This post on the math stack exchange gives a good method, which we will use here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/87238/32504).

(Originally I proposed a method sampling angles and distance from the origin - I accounted for nonuniformity in radius, but forgot about clustering at the poles. See the edit history if you're curious.)

```
max_dist = 5
draws = rnorm(3)
dist = runif(1) ^ (1/3)
offset = draws / sqrt(sum(draws^2)) * dist * max_dist
result = A + offset
```

Note that the question you link to is about extending a vector *in the same direction*, where your question wants a random direction.

Comment: Thanks, indeed looks good. It’s half of the coin,though. My question did not imply any direction, but it is good to generate “similar” set starting from a template.

Comment: Ah - after my edits I was always moving exactly the max distance. See the current version for a randomly chosen distance up to the max distance.